# Why do I keep getting http status 401 when trying to make a post request in Android studio/Java

Tags: java, android, http-post

[image]

In my Android app I'm making a post request to an URL. I tried to make the request with chrome extension "Advanced Rest Client" and I get the correct response with the correct status, but in my Android app I don't. I get http status 401 and this error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://95.85.53.176/nhi/api/app/session/get"

Here is my Java code -> this code works fine with all other post request i have tried, but not for this url.

```
public void req()
{
    try {

        String query = "access_token=xRO8OAiGGpPNjNP0jbPrb99g12vnRNsTcEwha9C2";

        URL url = new URL("http://95.85.53.176/nhi/api/app/session/get");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        //Set to POST
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        int status = connection.getResponseCode();

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "" + status);

        InputStream body = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(body));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        String s = response.toString();

        Log.d(LOGTAG, s);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.toString());

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: 401 is Unauthorized -- The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field.  If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials.

Comment: But how come is it working in "Advanced Rest Clien" extension (attached image)?

Comment: try without the leading http://

Comment: Not working. There needs to be a protocol.

Comment: ok, well check your back-end server logs to see why its refusing the connection. you may need to modify its web server settings to allow anonymus calls/origins from other domains